# A way to allocate a value to a particular place in Android

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to build Android app which gives a group of cricketers an allocated time in a cricket net based on the time available, the amount of people there and the amount of lanes available. One person can use the net at one time.

I have worked out a formula that works when there is an even amount of people and an even amount of  lanes but I cannot fathom a way when there is odd numbers of either or both.

Is there a way to allocate people between the lanes, I accept that people in one lane will have less time if there is an odd amount but I am not sure how to implement this.

My code is below:

```
package com.stuartroper.cricnets;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Session extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText numberOfPlayers;
    EditText numberOfNets;
    EditText hours;
    EditText minutes;
    double minutesPerPlayer;
    int hoursCalc;
    int minutesCalc;
    int playersNoCalc;
    int netsCalc;
    int [][] allocateLanes;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.session);

        numberOfPlayers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOfPlayers);
        numberOfNets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOfNets);
        minutes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutes);

        System.out.println("change of activity to game");
    }

    public void startSession(View view) {
        Log.i("Is button ever pressed", "Yes");

        hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hours);

        String hoursValue = hours.getText().toString();

        if (hours.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            hoursCalc = 0;
        } else {
            hoursCalc = Integer.parseInt(hoursValue);
        }
        //makeCalculation();

        numberOfPlayers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOfPlayers);
        String numberOfPlayersValue = numberOfPlayers.getText().toString();

        numberOfNets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOfNets);
        String numberOfNetsValue = numberOfNets.getText().toString();

        minutes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
        String minutesValue = minutes.getText().toString();

        if (numberOfPlayers.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || numberOfNets.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || minutes.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Incomplete, please add details in each field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            playersNoCalc = Integer.parseInt(numberOfPlayersValue);
            netsCalc = Integer.parseInt(numberOfNetsValue);
            minutesCalc = Integer.parseInt(minutesValue);
            makeCalculation();
        }
    }

    public void makeCalculation() {
        Log.i("Figures for calculation", "boom it works");
        Log.i("hoursCalc", "hoursCalc: " + hoursCalc);
        Log.i("hoursCalc", "hoursCalc: " + playersNoCalc);
        Log.i("hoursCalc", "hoursCalc: " + netsCalc);
        Log.i("hoursCalc", "hoursCalc: " + minutesCalc);

        if( playersNoCalc%2 == 1 || netsCalc %2==1 ){

        }else {
            minutesPerPlayer = ((hoursCalc * 60) + minutesCalc) / (playersNoCalc / netsCalc);
            Log.i("total", "minutesPerPlayer " + minutesPerPlayer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is about an algorithm.  It has nothing to do with Android.  To make this a better question, I suggest (a) Remove the Android tag, (b) remove the reference to Android in the question title, (c) Remove all Android app code, and leave only the Java code that represents your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Why is an odd number of lanes a problem?  I would make a spreadsheet of typical values and try to solve the problem equation on that first.  Then it will be easy to code.  If you have 10 bowlers and 5 lanes is that valid?  4 bowlers and 2 lanes?  15 bowlers and 10 lanes?  Figure out the problem on paper first.

Since original poster didn't work it out as suggested, I added a simple spreadsheet to help break down the problem before coding it.
http://docdro.id/AhYQc6d

Comment: It's just time allocated to a batsman in one lane . When I apply the formula with odd numbers the time allocated comes out wrong. If for example there are 5 batsman and 2 lanes it divides it initially to 2.5 which gives me the wrong allocated time.

Comment: Is 10 bowlers and 5 lanes valid?  I don't think you need to check if lanes is an even number.  Using the 5 bowlers and two lanes example what would you do if you were in charge of the lanes

Comment: I guess the issue is if there were 4 batsman and 3 lanes, I have considered an array in which the number of players is allocated one at a time, 1 into lane 1, 1 the next lane until each person has been allocated. If it was an odd number of people, say 7 people into 3 lanes, lane 1 would have 3 people then I could divide this by the time but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: Does the spreadsheet I made solve the algorithm successfully?